# Too many MasterDataSets?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, dataset

I'm writing a program in Visual Studio 2010 which is using an Access Database. Right now it has 6 Master Data Sets.

Each Dataset has a single tabular connection. Would it be better, if I instead used ONE MasterDataSet instead of the five or should I continue to use each of the Master Data Sets.

Below is a copy of my Solution Explorer to indicate what I mean:

[image: Screen capture of my Solution Explorer]

EDIT: Even better: If it should be better that I merge down into one, how would I go about starting this?

Answer (score 1):

This depends
if each dataset used in deferent form its better to keep them on the same way you did.
That if you put them on single dataset and you initialize this dataset on one form that use only one table from the six table existing on your dataset this will consume CPU to load the unwanted tables and memory for the unwanted table....

And if you are using two table as example on one screen its better to combine both in single, even the memory consumption will not differ if you distribute them to two dataset with single table on each one..

And also if you have some relation between some table like employee and Department and you want this data on single form its better to bring the two table on one dataset for view issue..to have the relation ready and don't build it on your code.....